# how do i count multiple rows in for loop with array?

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, for-loop

how do i count multiple rows in for loop  with array? when new row entered into mysql database for loop count new row as 0 when two new rows entered into mysql database for loop count both of rows as 1 ?? i don't know why `for loop escape first row count start from second row?` And also how do i make multiple rows session with array ??

**Function.php & Mysql Query**

```
function get_wid($id){
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid='$id'") 
                or die("Id Problem"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    $results= array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $results[] = $row['wid'];
    }
    return $results;
}
```

**Page Function Where I'm Calling $wid=get_wid($id);**

```
$wid=get_wid($id);
$max1= count($wid);
for($i>0; $i<$max1; $i++)
{
    $wid1=$wid [$i].'<br />';   
    $_SESSION['wid2']=$wid1;
    echo $_SESSION['wid2'];
}
```

**Now i'm using this function now this function didn't echo or print count 0 value not showing but values are showing after count 1 ?**

```
function get_wid($id){
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid='$id'") or die("Id     Problem"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
$results= array();
$i=1; // add the new line
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$results[$i] = $row['wid'];
$i++;
}
return $results;
}

$wid=get_wid($id);
$max1= count($wid);
for($i=1; $i<=$max1; $i++) // changes made here
{
$wid1=$wid [$i].'<br />';   
$_SESSION['wid2']=$wid1;
echo $_SESSION['wid2'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As has already been pointed out at your "Page Function Where I'm Calling $wid=get_wid($id);":

```
for($i>0; $i<$max1; $i++)
{
    $wid1=$wid [$i].'<br />';   
    $_SESSION['wid2']=$wid1;
    echo $_SESSION['wid2'];
}
```

$i>0 should be $i=0

I'm sure it was just a typo but you've failed to declare the start of the iteration which is why it only begins to process after the first. I would personally keep everything starting from 0 as is standard.

Just looking through I can also tell you that this piece:

```
$results=array();
$i=1; // add the new line
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$results[$i] = $row['wid'];
$i++;
}
```

would be a whole lot better as:

```
$results=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$results[] = $row['wid'];
}
```

This will keep it tighter. Another "tidy" tip is to add "_arr" to all array variables so that you know when you're referencing a string or array, e.g.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$results_arr[] = $row['wid'];
}
```

Although I don't know exactly what it is you're trying to achieve but I can say that you should be using a foreach to loop $wid. As mentioned when the iteration starts from 0 everything is easier because you can do this:

```
$wid=get_wid($id);

foreach($wid as $newWid) // changes made here
{  
$_SESSION['wid2']=$newWid.'<br />';
echo $_SESSION['wid2'];
}
```

If you want to get any indexes or specific values you can use the likes of [array_keys](http://www.php.net/array_keys), [array_search](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), etc. Lastly just as you did with the function "get_wid" I would call the other code from a function. Here's what I would do in total:

```
function get_wid($id){
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid='$id'") or die("Id     Problem"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
$results_arr= array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$results_arr[] = $row['wid'];
}
return $results_arr;
}

function sessionWid($id) {
$wid_arr=get_wid($id);
foreach($wid_arr as $wid) // changes made here
{  
$_SESSION['wid2']=$wid.'<br />';
echo $_SESSION['wid2'];
}

// call sessionWid($id) where you want
sessionWid($id);
```

I was going to leave it there but no idea why you would want a page break - `<br />` - in your session. You know if you want a page break between each array value you can output it like this:

```
echo implode('<br />',get_wid($id));
```

By keeping things clean you'll defintely save time from minor bugs that can kill a man!_g

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for($i=0; $i<count(get_wid($id)); $i++)
{
   $wid1=$wid[$i].'<br />';   
   $_SESSION['wid2']=$wid1;
   echo $_SESSION['wid2'];
}
```

`$i>0` Changed to `$i=0`

There was a space in `$wid [$i]` i changed it to `$wid[$i]`

Answer (score 0):

use foreach except for

```
$wids = get_wid($id);
foreach($wids as $wid )
{
  $wid1=$wid.'<br />';   
  $_SESSION['wid2']=$wid1;
  echo $_SESSION['wid2'];
}
```

Comment: still for loop escape first row count start from second row

Comment: use `var_export($wids)` to see the whole array information. maybe the problem depends on the database information

Answer (score 0):

Check have declare the $i variable outside or not

```
$wid=get_wid($id);

$max1= count($wid);

for($i=0; $i<$max1; $i++)

{

$wid1=$wid [$i].'<br />';  

$_SESSION['wid2']=$wid1;

echo $_SESSION['wid2'];

}
```

Comment: still for loop escape first row count start from second row

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_wid($id){
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid='$id'") or die("Id Problem"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
$results= array();
$i=1; // add the new line
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$results[$i] = $row['wid'];
$i++;
}
return $results;
}

$wid=get_wid($id);
$max1= count($wid);
for($i=1; $i<=$max1; $i++) // changes made here
{
$wid1=$wid [$i-1].'<br />';   
$_SESSION['wid2'][$i]=$wid1;
echo $_SESSION['wid2'];
}
```

query returns 3 records means
now,

```
$results[1]='1';
$results[2]='2';
$results[3]='3';
echo count($wid);


print_r($_SESSION['wid2']);
Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3)

$_SESSION['wid2'][1]='1';
$_SESSION['wid2'][2]='2';
$_SESSION['wid2'][3]='3';
```

and which returns all the values.and if you need the count of $_SESSION['wid2']

```
echo count($_SESSION['wid2']);
```

count=>3

Comment: for loop escape first row count start from second row

Comment: i used your function 

$wid=get_wid($id);
$max1= count($wid);
for($i=0; $i<$max1; $i++) // changes made here
{
$wid1=$wid [$i].'<br />';   
$_SESSION['wid2']=$wid1;
echo $_SESSION['wid2'];
}

why it is escape 0 value ?

Comment: for($i=1; $i<=$max1; $i++) // changes made here
{
$wid1=$wid [$i-1].'<br />';   
$_SESSION['wid2']=$wid1;
echo $_SESSION['wid2'];
}//now its working please check this.

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear exactly what you are trying to do here

Try this

```
for($i=0; $i<count(get_wid($id)); $i++)
{
echo $i;
 }
```

it will echo out 0,1,2,3, ......... up to  1-count(get_wid($id)

also what is in the  array at $wid[0],$wid[1],$wid[2]?

whatever is at that index is going to be echoed out each time.
hope this helps.

Comment: yes it is very possible that the problem is contained in the database column. just look at whats coming out of the id column in the wishlist table where the pid =$id.

Comment: aah, I think you need to do some tutorials on arrays and for loops it might be the best way. and then come back to your problem

Answer (score 0):

Set $i = 0 in the for loop it will start showing record in array at 0

Answer (score 0):

Just checkout this from your previous code

```
$wid=get_wid($id);
$max1= count($wid);
for($i=0; $i<=$max1; $i++)
{
    $wid1=$wid [$i].'<br />';   
    $_SESSION['wid'.($i+1)]=$wid1;
}

print_r($_SESSION);
```

I would like to mention here, in your code always you replace previous session with new. So your session always show the last row of your mysql data. Hope this code help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=1; $i<=$max1; $i++) // changes made here
{
$wid1=$wid [$i].'<br />';   
$_SESSION['wid2']=$wid1;
echo $_SESSION['wid2'];
}
```

I guess you are starting from the second row thats why it didnt show the first one(row 0)

changing

```
for($i=1; $i<=$max1; $i++)
```

to

```
for($i=0; $i<=$max1; $i++)
```

might fix your problem.